# ERROR:HDLParsers808 in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modulo, xilinx, hdl

I had in mind to take modulo for fixed point numbers in VHDL and I'm using fixed point package, I ran into this:

> ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "F:/prj/ofdm/test2.vhd" Line 53. mod can not have such operands in this context.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
library ieee_proposed;
use ieee_proposed.fixed_pkg.all;
use IEEE_PROPOSED.fixed_float_types.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
use IEEE.numeric_STD.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity test2 is
  port(
    clk    : in  std_logic;
    a1     : in  std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    --a2:in std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);
    output : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0)
    );
end test2;

architecture Behavioral of test2 is

  signal tmp : sfixed(3 downto -14) := "011001001000011111";  -- 4+12pi~=6.28314
begin
  process(clk)
  begin

    output <= to_slv(to_sfixed(a1, 5, -6) mod tmp);  --[4+14]
  --            tmp <= signed(a1)*signed(a2)*a;
  --            output <= std_logic_vector(tmp);
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You'll need to add your code and the exact error message text for anybody to be able to help.

Comment: @scary_jeff you're right i missed it!

Comment: so what is the description printed with your error 808, and what line does it refer to?

Comment: @scary_jeff ERROR:HDLParsers:808 - "F:/prj/ofdm/test2.vhd" Line 53. mod can not have such operands in this context. it refers to the line with the "mod" operation.

Comment: A 'if rising_edge(clk) then ' could help

Comment: anyhow: tool names and there versions is also nice-to-have info

Comment: @vermaete xilinx 14.7

Comment: The `mod` / `rem` operator is not synthesizable, because it involves a division. Anyhow, is mod defined for the types sfixed?

Comment: There is no line 53 in what you have posted

Comment: Your error does not match the code you have posted. The error complains about "rem" but your code only contains one usage of "mod". You should also consider removing the package `std_logic_arith` since it is considered obsolete. The `numeric_std` package is sufficient. Additionally you should move the use clause for `numeric_std` up to the corresponding library clause. The way the package is imported at the moment assumes that `numeric_std` is part of the `ieee_proposed` library.

Comment: @damage Thanks but it doesn't helped moving the numeric_std. and i still have the same error and i changed it to "rem" to see if it could help and it also didn't.

Comment: @Paebbels are you sure it is not synthesizable? if it's not then whats the use of it?? and by writing a test bench i and simulating it i get the right result for it!

Comment: VHDL can be used for simulation and synthesis. Only a subset of the VHDL statements, types, operators, ... is synthesizable. A divider is a really complex circuit in hardware and mostly not be inferred like an adder or a multiplier. Division and modulo operators are under rare circumstances synthesizable (e.g. for `/` if the second operand is constant and a power of 2). In most cases a division is a pipeline or iterative calculation. This involves a clock signal, which can not be applied to a operator, because it has only 2 inputs.

Comment: Even if `rem` is declared for INTEGER or (UN)SIGNED it does not mean, that is is declared for SFIXED. What's the use of it: It can be used in simulation environments to ease simulation code.

Comment: @Paebbels Tnx then, and do you have any idea about how can i scale some numbers into a period of [-pi to pi] without substituting the 2*pi multiples? i want to use it in a CORDIC IpCore for sine and cosine generation.

Comment: Do you need a high resolution output? CORDIC is big compared to a lookup table (LUT). In most cases it's a good solution to store sine and cosine values in a LUT. For example our VHDL library PoC has a module [PoC.mem.lut.Sine](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/lut/lut_Sine.vhdl#L42-L55) that stores a sine table in BlockRAM. It can be configured for cosine (offset = 90.0 deg), too. The parameter quarters is used to save memory, because the quarters 2 to 4 can be generated by inverting or mirroring quarter 1.

Comment: Using PI: In most cases PI is not needed for the calculation, it can be hidden by offset / bias calculations and scaling. If you scale the range [-PI .. PI] to [0 .. 4095], you calculate `mod PI` by just slicing a bit vector. Only at the end of a calculation PI is needed to calculate the result. I don't know you algorithm, so I can't go into details.

Comment: Just as info: In Libero v11.5SP2 (Synplify Pro) for the Igloo2 (M2GL005) FPGA the 'mod' on 'sfixed' does compile and implement when selecting 'vhdl-2008' as option for the synthesis tool.  But the result isn't small nor fast.